# count Repeated characters

Tags: javascript

I want to count repeated characters in input order. Here is my code.

```
<textarea id="field"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="GO" />
<div id="charNum"></div>
```

and

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
    var all = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var str = $("#field").val();
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        var char = all.charAt(i);
        if (str.split(char).length > 1) text += str.split(char).length - 1 + "<br>";
    }
    $("#charNum").html(text);
});
```

If I enter `'mmani'` I get the output `'1121'`, it checks by alphabet order. I want output like this: `'2111'`.

Comment: the problem is you're looping the  `all` string which is in alphabetical order. This variable is also of no use as I don't think the alphabet will change anytime soon. Actually I think you took the problem from the wrong side, but it's hard to be sure without the context.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve with this 'solution'?

Comment: yes, if i change str.length instead all.length means.. it checks every character.. 'aabbc' output is '22221'. but i need output '221'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
        var uniqueOccurence = "";
        var str = $("#field").val();
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if(uniqueOccurence.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) < 0)
            uniqueOccurence += str.charAt(i);
        }

        var text = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < uniqueOccurence .length; i++) {
            var char = uniqueOccurence .charAt(i);
            if (str.split(char).length > 1) text += str.split(char).length - 1 + "<br>";
        }
        $("#charNum").html(text);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please have a look on the comments in the code for Explanation.**

```
var k = "mamma mia miami".split('')

//if you want to exclude spaces
//var k = "mamma mia miami".split(/\s+/).join('').split('')

var p = {};
//count frequency of every character
for(var i=0;i<k.length;i++) {
    var currentChar = k[i];
    if(p[currentChar] == undefined) {
        //initialize counter for new char found
        p[currentChar]=1;
    } else {
        //increment counter for every next match for that char
        p[currentChar]++;
    }
}

var output = '';
//format output according to your need
for(each in p) {
    output += p[each]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're overcomplicating it, instead of looping over the entire alphabet, why not just loop over the characters in the value, and count the number of occurrences?

```
var charCount = {};
$.each(this.value.split(''), function(i, v) {
    charCount[v] = charCount[v] + 1 || 1; 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X93F7/29/)

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to do this is to just compare `str.charAt(i)` to `str.charAt(i+1)`:

```
for(var i=1; i<str.length; i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i-1)) {
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gffsQ/)

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly try this example:

**script**

```
var duplicateCount = function(v)
{
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    console.log("text is: " + v);
    v = v.split('');
    var map = {}, c, t;
    for(var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i ++)
    {
        c = v[i];
        t = 0;
        if(map[c])
        {
            t = map[c];
            map[c] = ++ t;
        }
        else
        {
            map[c] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(map);
    var arr = [];
    for(var k in map)
    {
        arr.push(map[k]);
    }
    out.value = arr.join('');
};
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="duplicateCount(this.value);" placeholder="Text here"/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="output"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a regular Expression.

**Solution:**

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
    var str = $("#field").val();
    var text = str.match(/([a-z])\1?/g).map(function(a) {return a.length}).join('');

    $("#charNum").html(text); // Will be '2111'
});
```

**What it does:**

The regular expression matches every character (`[a-z]`) and all of it's repeating occurences ( `\1` references the first parentheses group, which contains the matched character), using the `g` flag to apply it to all of the string.

The returned value of this would be an array of the matches like this:

```
[ "mm", "a", "n", "i" ]
```

Mapping over these and replacing them with their length (`[ 2, 1, 1, 1 ]`), and then joining the returned string will yield the expected result: `"2111"`

Not sure how you would want to deal with occurences of >= 10 of the same characters, though.

Since `Array.prototype.map` is not supported in IE8 and below, here's a solution avoiding that function:

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
    var str = $("#field").val();
    var matches = str.match(/([a-z])\1?/g);
    var text = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        text = text + matches[i].length;
    }

    $("#charNum").html(text); // Will be '2111'
});
```